# c# move picturebox from an array of picturebox up when you hover mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse, picturebox

I'm working on C# windows form. I have an array of picturebox, displayed on the form. The array has the size of 13, and they're all side by side. How can I make it so that when I click on a picturebox, it is moved up by let's say +20 on y.
My code to make the picture boxes. The pb1 and p1 are declared above

```
void print_Deck(int x, int y, double[] a){
        double n;
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {

            pb1[i] = new PictureBox();
            // pb1[1].Image = Properties.Resources.img1;
            pb1[i].Visible = true;
            pb1[i].Location = new Point(0, 0);
            this.Size = new Size(800, 600);
            pb1[i].Size = new Size(46, 65);
            pb1[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pb1[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
            n= a[i];
            im = face(n);
            pb1[i].Image = im;
            this.Controls.Add(pb1[i]);
            x = x + 20;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding Click event on your Picturebox then you can try this code on the Click function.

You can manipulate the location by using Top propery.

```
Picturebox.Top -= 20; // move the picture box upward
```

or

```
Picturebox.Top += 20; // move the picture box downward
```

or use the .Location = New Point(X,Y)

```
Picturebox.Location = new Point(Picturebox.Location.X, Picturebox.Location.Y + 20);
```

Here's how you add the EventHandler to your picturebox.

```
Picturebox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Picturebox_ClickFunction);
```

then create a fucntion with the name Picturebox_ClickFunction

```
private void Picturebox_ClickFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     PictureBox pb1 = (PictureBox)sender; // you need to cast(convert) the sende to a picturebox object so you can access the picturebox properties
}
```

then you can use the code I provided above.

Comment: how can I add the click event to the array of picturebox when they're made during run time, and their numbers will change later on in the code. Currently it's just a rough draft

Comment: since your picturebox are dynamic, you can you the System.EventHandler.

Comment: Could you show me an example of  how I would be able to do with event handler? I'll greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: to move up the picturebox, i'll have to put that code in the picturebox_clickFuntion, right? Also , where exactly am I putting that event handler code? for it to be picked up when i click on the picturebox in runtime?

Comment: you can add it after you initialize a new Picturebox. pb1[i] = new PictureBox();  then used the EventHandler on pb1[i] like this pb1[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Picturebox_ClickFunction);

Answer (score 0):

You can try [PictureBox.Top](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.top(v=vs.110).aspx) property with [Anchor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx) property
or use [PictureBox.Location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could register the [PictureBox's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx) 'Click' event to adjust the 'Margin' property by the required amount